# Can't get value of a button using Page.Request.Form[i]

Tags: c#, html, forms, post

My html looks this way:

```
<button type="submit" class="img" name="save" value="0">Speichern</button>
<button type="submit" class="img" name="save" value="1">Speichern und Schließen</button>**
```

When i parse the request by using Page.Request.Form[i] the value of the key "save" is "Speichern und Schließen" and not 1 an I don't see any possibility to get the correct value. Is there a way to get the correct value (0 or 1 and not "Speichern und Schließen")?

Comment: Which browser (name,version) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  tag defines a push button.

Inside a button element you can put content, like text or images. This is the difference between this element and buttons created with the input element.

Always specify the type attribute for the button. The default type for Internet Explorer is "button", while in other browsers (and in the W3C specification) it is "submit".

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp